# Stubbing function with jest

Tags: javascript, mocking, jestjs

I understand that this is the basic function of `jest` and I *should* be able to figure it out with the docs and other online resources, but somehow I cannot, so I apologise in advance if this is trivial.

I'm trying to test a function in Javascript that performs a few operations using other modules, as well as `localStorage`, and I would like to stub out the other modules and the call to `localStorage`. The documentation that I found for Jest seemed far too simplistic for me to adapt to my use case, like declaring a `mock` and then calling it inside the test - this doesn't happen in my case, as the function I want to mock is being called internally by my function, I'm not passing it in as a dependency. Let me give some code to explain: file name is `dataInLocalStorage.js`

```
import serialize from './serialize'; // simple module that serialises data
import deserialize from './deserialize'; // simple module that deserialises data
import findObject from './findObject'; // find an object in the deserialised data

const addDataToLocalStorage = (data) => {
  const dataStored = deserialize(localStorage.getItem('data')); // fetch data from localStorage
  const isStored = !!findObject(dataStored, data); // check whether the data I want to store is already there

  if (isStored) { return null; } // if data is already stored, skip

  const serializedData = serialize(data); // serialise data to be stored

  return localStorage.setItem('data', serializedData); // store serialised data in localStorage
};

export { addDataToLocalStorage };
```

The purpose os this module is just to store data in `localStorage` in a serialised way, but in an additive way, so that adding data doesn't remove previously stored data, and no duplicates are added either.

Anyway, my test file looks like this: file name is `dataInLocalStorage.test.js`

```
import { addDataToLocalStorage } from '../dataInLocalStorage';

describe('addDataToLocalStorage', () => {
  const deserialize = jest.fn();

  beforeAll(() => {
    localStorage.removeItem('data');
  });

  const data = {
    name: 'johnny'
  };

  addDataToLocalStorage(data);

  it('adds the data to local storage', () => {
    expect(deserialize).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Here is the rather unsurprising error for this attempt.

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

Expected mock function to have been called, but it was not called.

      17 |
      18 |   it('adds the data to local storage', () => {
    > 19 |     expect(deserialize).toHaveBeenCalled();
         |                         ^
      20 |   });
      21 | });
```

On top of this I tried importing the `deserialize` function here in the test file and adding a `jest.mock` on that, which didn't work either.

Note that this isn't my code 100%, I have modified it for simplicity in order to make it easier to read for you, sorry if there are some slight mismatches, I tried my best to be as diligent as possible while converting it.

If you know what you're looking at, you'll see that this is obviously not working. Using other (more useful) expectations, the test was passing, but adding some console logs in the `deserialize` file showed that it's still running, when the idea is that I would like to mock it and provide my own return value.

---

*Side note*: I came from Ruby on Rails where mocking with RSpec is pretty simple, and I was hoping it would be just as simple with Jest. It likely is, but I can't wrap my head around it, as it doesn't seem possible to make a direct reference to the function/module I want to mock. In RSpec, doing `allow(MySerializer).to receive(:call).and_return(...)` would do the trick and I wouldn't have to worry about that module being called during the test.

Comment: @skyboyer thanks for the edit, sorry for the initial mistake

Comment: nevermind, not big deal to fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the value of `deserialize` to a jest mock, you are changing the variable value, not setting a reference that your code is using. To keep it a reference it needs to be a value in an object.

To import an object you can use `import * as deserialize from "./deserialize";`.
Then you can set the mock on the reference with `deserialize.default = jest.fn()`.

https://codesandbox.io/s/88wlzp6q88

```
import { useIt } from "./use-default-export";

import * as myfunc from "./default-export-function";

test("use-default-export-function", () => {
  expect(useIt()).toEqual("real");
});

test("use-default-export-function with mock", () => {
  myfunc.default = jest.fn(() => "unreal");
  expect(useIt()).toEqual("unreal");
});
```

in your test it'll be..

```
import { addDataToLocalStorage } from '../dataInLocalStorage';
import * as deserialize from './deserialize';
...
deserialize.default = jest.fn();
```

**alternate TS compat version..**
(which is actually cleaner all round..)

```
import { useIt } from "./use-default-export";

import myfunc from "./default-export-function";

jest.mock("./default-export-function", () => jest.fn());

test("use-default-export-function with mock", () => {
  useIt();
  expect(myfunc).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

**return/resolve different values per test**
(need to cast to `jest.Mock` to be able to use `jest.fn()` functions)

```
test("use-default-export-function with mock", () => {
  const aFunc = myfunc as jest.Mock;
  aFunc.mockResolvedValue("bar");
  useIt();
  expect(useIt()).resolves.toEqual("bar");
});

test("use-default-export-function with mock 2", () => {
  const aFunc = myfunc as jest.Mock;
  aFunc.mockReturnValue("foo");
  useIt();
  expect(useIt()).toEqual("foo");
});
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but this is giving me a linting error of `Cannot assign to 'default' because it is a read-only property.` - it might have been useful to note that I'm using TypeScript and this is a tslint error, but I didn't think it was really crucial to the problem.

Comment: mm, bugga. I don't have an env to test this (and codesandbox doesn't support jest.mock as yet) but you could try replacing the assignment with `jest.mock("./default-export-function", { default: jest.fn(() => "unreal") });`, or it might need to be `jest.mock("./default-export-function", () => ({ default: jest.fn(() => "unreal") }));` or similar. That *might* get you past the TS nagging...

Comment: Sadly, neither of those were any use. Unless I'm not mocking the path properly, I tried both absolute and relative paths to the file in question, but that was unsuccessful. I will get some advice from colleagues today (I was trying to get some work done over the weekend, guess that backfired) and give an update if we can figure it out. Thanks for your help regardless

Comment: I've added a working variation to my answer (tested with TS), sorry for the run-around.

Comment: thanks for the update - this is working for me now! I believe it was to do with the placement of the mock, which I had in the `beforeEach` method. Once I moved it outside of the outermost `describe` it worked! my next issue is that I need the return value to be different per test (hence why it was in the `beforeEach`. it's outside the scope of this question, so I accepted your answer, but if you have any advice on this matter, I would be happy to hear it, but regardless thanks for your help!

Comment: no worries at all. (and examples for custom test mocks added 8)